# Paypal Checkout SDK missing card type or card brand fields

Tags: java, paypal

i try to works with Paypal Checkout sdk version 1.0.2, and in documentation i saw common definitions block where was described card_type field [Documentation. CardBrand](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-card_brand)
and second is [Documentation card_response.brand](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-card_response)
But in the model in source code i did't see what this fields are return in response.
For example above source code Order.class

```java
package com.paypal.orders;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.paypal.http.annotations.*;
/**
 * The order details.
 */
@Model
public class Order {

    // Required default constructor
    public Order() {}

    /**
    * The intent to either capture payment immediately or authorize a payment for an order after order creation.
    */
    @SerializedName("intent")
    private String checkoutPaymentIntent;

    public String checkoutPaymentIntent() { return checkoutPaymentIntent; }

    public Order checkoutPaymentIntent(String checkoutPaymentIntent) {
        this.checkoutPaymentIntent = checkoutPaymentIntent;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The date and time, in [Internet date and time format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6). Seconds are required while fractional seconds are optional.<blockquote><strong>Note:</strong> The regular expression provides guidance but does not reject all invalid dates.</blockquote>
    */
    @SerializedName("create_time")
    private String createTime;

    public String createTime() { return createTime; }

    public Order createTime(String createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The date and time, in [Internet date and time format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6). Seconds are required while fractional seconds are optional.<blockquote><strong>Note:</strong> The regular expression provides guidance but does not reject all invalid dates.</blockquote>
    */
    @SerializedName("expiration_time")
    private String expirationTime;

    public String expirationTime() { return expirationTime; }

    public Order expirationTime(String expirationTime) {
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The ID of the order.
    */
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    public String id() { return id; }

    public Order id(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * An array of request-related [HATEOAS links](/docs/api/reference/api-responses/#hateoas-links). To complete payer approval, use the `approve` link with the `GET` method.
    */
    @SerializedName(value = "links", listClass = LinkDescription.class)
    private List<LinkDescription> links;

    public List<LinkDescription> links() { return links; }

    public Order links(List<LinkDescription> links) {
        this.links = links;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The customer who approves and pays for the order. The customer is also known as the payer.
    */
    @SerializedName("payer")
    private Payer payer;

    public Payer payer() { return payer; }

    public Order payer(Payer payer) {
        this.payer = payer;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * An array of purchase units. Each purchase unit establishes a contract between a customer and merchant. Each purchase unit represents either a full or partial order that the customer intends to purchase from the merchant.
    */
    @SerializedName(value = "purchase_units", listClass = PurchaseUnit.class)
    private List<PurchaseUnit> purchaseUnits;

    public List<PurchaseUnit> purchaseUnits() { return purchaseUnits; }

    public Order purchaseUnits(List<PurchaseUnit> purchaseUnits) {
        this.purchaseUnits = purchaseUnits;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The order status.
    */
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    public String status() { return status; }

    public Order status(String status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    /**
    * The date and time, in [Internet date and time format](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6). Seconds are required while fractional seconds are optional.<blockquote><strong>Note:</strong> The regular expression provides guidance but does not reject all invalid dates.</blockquote>
    */
    @SerializedName("update_time")
    private String updateTime;

    public String updateTime() { return updateTime; }

    public Order updateTime(String updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Did any know how i can get information about payment\order where will be fields cardType, or cardBrand?

ideal case will be if i can get shortly informaton about card:

1. CardHolder
2. Last digital card number
3. expires
4. Country who release card

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are there for integrations that use them, such as those who have integrated [Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/), presumably (which has certain country availability).

The fields do not apply to normal PayPal transactions and aren't mapped in most checkout SDKs.